# React custom hook runs useEffect multiple time

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook that only have useEffects and returns null. I am using it in App.js file. But now i have to return a function and import that custom hook some in other component. But when i call that custom hook in another component. useEffects run too (cause multiple times and that is the problem). But i only need them to run once in App.js file.

I solve this with this if statement. I pass isApp true in App.js and i don't in other component. But is there some other way to solve that. I didn't like that approach

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!props?.isApp)
        return;

    func();
}, [
    someDependencies
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same thing, x number of components used my custom Hook which meant that every time the custom Hook was called the `useEffect(s)` would be executed.

To correct this, the best way is to place the logic of the `useEffect` in a function inside the hook, then call it in some component that is elevated in the component tree, in this way the function will only be executed once since it only a component is the one that has the `useEffect`.

**Before:**

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {

    useEffect( () => {
        //  Load user location...
    }, [] );

};

export const HomePage = () => {

    useCustomHook();

    return (
        // Jsx...
    );
};
```

**After:**

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {

    const loadUserLocation = async () => {
        // Load user location...
    };

    return {
        loadUserLocation
    };

};

export const HomePage = () => {

    const { loadUserLocation } = useCustomHook();

    useEffect( () => {
        loadUserLocation();
    }, [] );

    return (
        // Jsx...
    );
};
```

And if your `useEffect` has any dependency from your custom Hook, it would only be enough to export it and use it in the component's `useEffect`.

I hope it helps you and anyone reading this. All the best!

Answer (score -1):

a. If you only want to run once!

useEffect(() =>{ func(); }, []);

b. If you want to run once based on deps.

```
function useCall(callback, condition = true) {
  const ref = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (condition && !ref.current) {
      ref.current = true;
      callback();
    }
  }, [callback, condition]);
}

useCall(()=>{ }, isCondition);
```